# MDADM Config file

Tags: configuration, mdadm

So I've asked a few similiar questions before, but my RAID continues to break. Im not sure whats going on. I really need to redo the whole thing.

Right now, my /dev/md127 is "inactive"

In the steps I have found in attempts to activate it, I am getting a message stating that :"/dev/md127 not identified in config file"

I've tried to search a bit, but I'm not confident I have found anything to proceed. Can someone please help me get this RAID going? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed my md127 issue like this:

Stop the array if not stopped already:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md127
```

Reassemble the array on md0:

```
mdadm -A /dev/md0 /dev/sd[abcd...]
```

Get the UUID from the *mdadm --detail /dev/md0* command and use it to edit the mdadm.conf file:

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=9b2f9d1b:da9a4665:67bbc40f:fdaf6034
```

Once that is done, use *update-initramfs* and reboot the system.

This should do the trick.

Comment: So I did what you suggested, and I am getting a message back stating "assembled from 4 drives and 1 spare, not enough to start the array."

Comment: So...I actually did assemble but using --force, and it seemed to do the trick. Thanks very much

Comment: I take that back, it ceased again...

Comment: What error messages are you seeing in the logs after the forced assembly?

Comment: well, the --detail shows that its all messed up, 2 drives are inactive and one is all of a sudden a spare elsewhere. Im really not sure whats going on. I rebooted, and Im trying to zero the superblocks, when i get to the last drive /def/sdf1, it states "couldnt open /dev/sdf1 for write - not zeroing" Im not sure how to proceed